# GCC's implementation of angle-brackets includes. Why does it have to be as described below?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, language-lawyer

[This document](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp.pdf) in its section **2.6 Computed Includes** has the following paragraph:

> If the line expands to a token stream beginning with a < token and
>   including a >  token, then the tokens between the <  and the
>   first > are combined to form the filename to be included. Any
>   whitespace between tokens is reduced to a single space; **then any space
>   after the initial < is retained, but a trailing space before the
>   closing > is ignored**. CPP searches for the file according to the rules
>   for angle-bracket includes.

I know this is implementation defined, but why does it have to be this way for GCC? I'm referring specifically to the highlighted sentence above.

**EDIT**

I have just noticed that the third paragraph before the one quoted above says the following:

> You must be careful when you define the macro. `#define` saves tokens,
>   not text. The preprocessor has no way of knowing that the macro will
>   be used as the argument of `#include`, so it generates ordinary
>   tokens, not a header name. This is unlikely to cause problems if you
>   use double-quote includes, which are close enough to string constants.
>   **If you use angle brackets, however, you may have trouble**.

Does anyone know what kind of trouble is being pointed out here?

Comment: Best guess is that the developers of GCC think that having spaces at the end of a filename is an abomination.

Comment: Filenames with leading and/or trailing spaces are very finicky to wok with, especially on Windows.

Comment: Just because it has been defined like that, does not necessarily mean that it has to be defined like that. It is not mandated by the standard.

Comment: Visual Studio removes both initial and ending space, so behaves differently. HP aCC behaves like gcc (perhaps for compatibility reasons).

Comment: Sometimes documentation simply describes what the code happens to do instead of the other way around, especially in cases that don't matter (you can use any space anywhere if you use double quotes).

Comment: @rustyx Did you see my **Edit** above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess the implementor chose the simplest way when they implemented this functionality, without giving it much thought.

It seems that the initial implementation landed in 2000-07-03 (two decades ago!). The relevant part looks like ([source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/041c31944c94d5ee089bd569c4361fbc3d2acaea/gcc/cpplex.c#L499-L509)):

```c
  for (;;)
    {
      t = cpp_get_token (pfile);
      if (t->type == CPP_GREATER || t->type == CPP_EOF)
        break;

      CPP_RESERVE (pfile, TOKEN_LEN (t));
      if (t->flags & PREV_WHITE)
        CPP_PUTC_Q (pfile, ' ');
      pfile->limit = spell_token (pfile, t, pfile->limit);
    }
```

Notably, it breaks out when it sees the `CPP_GREATER` token (i.e. `>`), *before* reserving memory for the token. This makes sense, since there's no need to allocate memory when the token will not be written to the buffer.

Then, only *after* memory is reserved, the preprocessor checks whether the token has preceding whitespace (`t->flags & PREV_WHITE`) and when it does, writes a whitespace character to the buffer.

As a result, in `< foo / bar >`, only the whitespaces before `foo` (that is, after the initial `<`), `/`, and `bar` are kept.

Comment: But isn't  it the case that the condition `if (t->flags & PREV_WHITE)  CPP_PUTC_Q (pfile, ' ');` contradicts what's being said in the document: "Any whitespace between tokens is reduced to a single space; ..."?